# NameError: name 'img' is not defined

Tags: python

в python файл «Распознавание жестов» возвращает ошибку при запуске последвотельно 2 раза из другые файлы с помощью метода exec(open('file.py')) , но он работает при запуске самого файла. Подскажите пожалуйста есть ли ещё другые варианты?

файл A

```
exec(open('subjects.py').read())
```

файл subjects.py

```
success, img = cap.read()
img = cv2.flip(img, 1)
hands, img = detector.findHands(img, flipType=False)
....
....
exec(open('Matem.py').read())
```

нет проблем с библиотекой или версией. Основная ошибка при запуске файла через несколько файлов.

Надеюсь, мой вопрос был ясен. Потому что это мой первый вопрос на этом сайте)

Comment: Покажите дескриптор ошибки от А до Я.

Comment: забудьте на время о ``exec()``. Вы эту функцию неправильно применяете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

исправил ошибку импортируя в файле A subjects на функцию, где должен запускаться файл subjects.py

```
def func():
    ...
    import subjects
    subjects 
    ...
```

Comment: Если вам нужно импортировать модуль зная его имя как имя файла то пишите так: `__import__("<Имя файла>")`

Answer (score 0):

Как один из вариантов, Вы можете использовать функцию для передачи переменной `img` между файлами. Таким образом Вам не придется передавать эту переменную через аргументы командной строки или глобальные переменные.

**Файл `subject.py`:**

```python
def get_image():
    success, img = cap.read()
    img = cv2.flip(img, 1)
    hands, img = detector.findHands(img, flipType=False)
    return img
    ...
```

**Файл `A`:**

```python
from subjects import get_image

img = get_image()
```

Comment: это вариант не помогло. Ошибку показивает в файле subjects.py

Comment: Ошибка аналогичная? Дополните пожалуйста вопрос, полным ее описанием, внесу соответствующие изменения в ответ. Возможно будет достаточно внести переменные в функцию, по примеру: `def get_image(***, detector):`; `img = get_image(***, detector)`, где `***` - объект видеозахвата библиотеки `OpenCV`.